# What is the minimum time for hangfire jobs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

I create an `Asp.Net Core 3.1` project with `hangfire`. I configured `hangfire` to run every second but it's run every 15 second or more.
This is my `ConfigureService`

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddScoped<IShowDate, ShowDate>();
    services.AddHangfire(x =>
    {
        x.UseMemoryStorage();
    });
    services.AddHangfireServer();
}
```

`Configure` Method

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IShowDate>(job => job.Print(), "*/1 * * * * *");

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseHangfireDashboard();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapHangfireDashboard();
    });
}
```

`ShowDate` Class

```cs
public interface IShowDate
{
    Task Print();
}
public class ShowDate : IShowDate
{
    public async Task Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Example {DateTime.Now}");
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Result

```
Example 9/8/2020 10:46:14 AM
Example 9/8/2020 10:46:29 AM
Example 9/8/2020 10:46:44 AM
Example 9/8/2020 10:46:59 AM
Example 9/8/2020 10:47:14 AM
Example 9/8/2020 10:47:29 AM
Example 9/8/2020 10:47:44 AM
Example 9/8/2020 10:47:59 AM
Example 9/8/2020 10:48:14 AM
Example 9/8/2020 10:48:29 AM
Example 9/8/2020 10:48:44 AM
Example 9/8/2020 10:48:59 AM
Example 9/8/2020 10:49:14 AM
Example 9/8/2020 10:49:29 AM
Example 9/8/2020 10:49:44 AM
Example 9/8/2020 10:49:59 AM
```

How can i run job every seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the default `SchedulePollingInterval` to 1 seconds

```cs
services.AddHangfireServer(option =>
{
    option.SchedulePollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The default schedule polling interval is set to 15s.Maybe you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38367398/hangfire-recurring-tasks-under-minute),and you can try what `WtFudgE` says.